# Вывод данных из SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Делаю Android приложение, как можно сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки на одном фрагменте выводились данные из БД в textView и Image в другом? Кнопок несколько следовательно и данные должны по каждой выводиться соответствующие.

Comment: это может вам помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751594/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-sqlite-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4/751607#751607

Comment: Передавайте во второй фрагмент информацию о том, какая кнопка была нажата и уже в нём получайте данные из БД.